# How to move already running processes to different `cgroup` with systemd?

Tags: 20.04, systemd, cgroup, resource-limiting

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with MATE desktop which doesn't natively support launching desktop UI and window manager in a separate cgroup from the other applications.

Is it possible to run some `systemd` specific commands via `.xsessionrc` to create nested `cgroup` as child of `user@${UID}.service` and move selected processes there? I'd prefer something that doesn't require `sudo` or `root` so that the required commands could be safely executed by the respective user account (with the effective user id `$UID`).

Basically I'm looking for real world replacements for following imaginary commands

```
systemd-cgroup-create --parent "user@${UID}.service" "gui-desktop@${UID}.slice"
systemd-cgroup-move-process --to "gui-desktop@${UID}.slice" $(pgrep --uid $UID marco) $(pgrep --uid $UID mate-panel) $(pgrep --uid $UID mate-session)
systemd-cgroup-modify --set "MemoryMin=1G" --set "IOWeight=1000" "gui-desktop@${UID}.slice"
```

All I can see is `systemd-run` but that only supports starting a single process instead of manipulating already existing processes.

I know that `cgclassify` and similar old tools can technically do this given `root` acces but `systemd` expects that it's the sole source of modifications to the cgroup hierarchy so this would need to be done via `systemd` specific commands.